# TypeScript Generics Don't Apply To Previous Function When Curried, How To?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, currying

I have a curried version of `map` that handles promises. It takes two arguments, one at a time. It takes two type parameters to let the caller provide pieces that can't be inferred. However, in practice the caller always has to provide them because the types aren't inferred in the transform function they pass in. The function looks like this:

```
/**
 * @description
 *   Like `ramda.map`, but handles an iterator that returns a promise (or not).
 *
 * @example
 *   await mapP((x: number) => Promise.resolve(x + 1))([1, 2, 3]) // -> [2, 3, 4]
 */
export const mapP = <T, R>(xf: (value: T) => Promise<R> | R) => (
  data: T[],
): Promise<R[]> => pipe(when(isNil, always([])), map(xf), allP)(data)
```

Here's me calling it and you can see that the `x` is no known by the type system.

[image]

How can I fix the way I'm writing the function to have the types work (without abandoning currying- I know it would figure it out if not curried)?

Comment: This is probably not the case but can you make sure this doesn't compile. I want to make sure it's not just the IDE's type inference that's bad

Comment: Yeah, confirmed that `tsc` shows the same error.

Comment: Please post code as text also and not only as an image (see [ask] for more info).  I'd love to be able to copy and paste this into a standalone IDE to suggest an answer but right now I can't.  A [mcve] goes a long way toward getting a good answer. Good luck!

Comment: Also, given that someone should be able to write `const f = mapP(x => x.name)` and then later `f(data)`, how would you suggest the compiler know that `x` is of type `Foo`?  Does `mapP((x: Foo)=>x.name)(data)` meet your needs?  The primary issue here seems to be that contextual type inference doesn't reach backward from `data` through to the type of `x` in the previous function call.

Comment: @jcalz yeah, my thoughts exactly. I don't know how it could know in the former case, but was hoping there was some magic that I didn't know about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to use the following declaration:

```
declare const mapP: <T, R>(xf: (value: T) => Promise<R> | R) => (
  data: T[],
) => Promise<R[]>;
```

which is the same as your version but doesn't worry about implementation.  Anyway, you've run into the issue where the following fails to infer the type of `x` in the callback:

```
const res = mapP(x => x.name)(data); // error!
// x is unknown ----> ~
```

It's not *completely* unreasonable to expect that the compiler might infer that `x` has to be of type `Foo` because `data` is of type `Foo[]`.  There is such a thing as [contextual typing](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) in which the compiler will infer types "backwards in time", by looking at how something is used and figuring out what type it *should have been declared to be* for that to work.  Unfortunately it's a bit too much of a stretch for the compiler to do this backwards through multiple function calls.  Oh well.

---

The big appeal of currying, in my opinion, is to be able to partially apply a function and then use that partially-applied function *later*, like this:

```
const f = mapP(x => x.name); // error!
// x is unknown --> ~

// later

const res2 = f(data);
```

In this case, it would be implausible to expect the compiler could know anything useful about `x`, especially in light of other possible calls like this:

```
const res3 = f([{ name: false }]);
```

where `x` should be a `{name: boolean}` instead of a `Foo`.  If your intent in `x => x.name` is that `x` should be a `Foo`, you will need to communicate that intent to the compiler, via a type annotation:

```
const res4 = mapP((x: Foo) => x.name)(data); // okay Promise<string[]>
```

This is the solution I'd recommend to your question as stated; you are not requiring that the developer manually specify `T` and `R` when you call `mapP()`.  Instead, you are annotating the callback's parameter so that the compiler *can* infer `T` and `R` itself, which it does.

Note that you could even get more fancy and communicate "I'd like the callback to apply to *anything* with a `name` property and return a value of that type", by using a *generic* callback:

```
const g = mapP(<T>(x: { name: T }) => x.name);

const res5 = g(data); // Promise<string[]>;
const res6 = g([{ name: false }]); // Promise<boolean[]>;
```

And here the compiler can use some of its [higher order type inference](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) introduced in TS3.4 to see that `g()` is itself a generic function.

---

So, backing up: if your use case is really to immediately consume the partially-applied function by calling it without holding a reference to it, you should probably do that without currying.   The "best of both worlds" approach might be an overloaded hybrid function that is both curried and not-curried:

```
function mapQ<T, R>(xf: (value: T) => Promise<R> | R, data: T[]): Promise<R[]>;
function mapQ<T, R>(xf: (value: T) => Promise<R> | R): (data: T[]) => Promise<R[]>;
function mapQ<T, R>(
  xf: (value: T) => Promise<R> | R,
  data?: T[]
): ((data: T[]) => Promise<R[]>) | Promise<R[]> {
  return data ? mapQ(xf)(data) : mapQ(xf);
}
```

Then you can use it curried if and only if your intent is to use the function later:

```
const res7 = mapQ(x => x.name, data); // okay Promise<string[]>
const h = mapQ((x: Foo) => x.name);
const res8 = h(data); // okay Promise<string[]>
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gWygBwAUAueAHgBUAaeAJQD4AKADwDMSGA3KCAVxBPIBKeAF468AjCTYAlmhCl68AD61hY+AwBQ8eMCgYoAgNoBdSlvXjJ0uQppm6Abh1aMATzwIAYkiSj4AG94FChsfnhMGBkUAHN4AF8XUEhYBGR0LH1DEgBBGBgod1JfJGctLQzMeDg0ANxCZlFxJgA6UPDBBmyoQS0Aen74Jng5eB4UAGsUJAB3FHgAWmXF8QA-CqqsFnr8AiaNNo6QQSd4QfgQAqQYAEIBoZGxiem5heX1h-hoDCvN1GqtQATAEWN0DL0XFsaiA0ABmUEMYzBY4kFjceSJUynSoArC1AAsu0azBIpSsw3aYRO4MMp3OQyQkyKEiksnkpCiMVijlxmXg8REOD2DAojCYJBR1IEiQpR2pOL5gNhAFYArFaZCGazbByuXFHFC8TC0AA2dVIqXhNEYhAJbFnC42dkKABGfggICgKENFS0LAmYAwMlQwrwAEUKNR6Mw2JouLwIkJmjqXYpxKoaNQeiZsSRnXZFL6AyggyGFg1I1RaOK45xuHwBBSCxylJnBOwc-ByGZm2zCw5TOUS2XQ5WozXtLpWOwE43u33dfYM7QLLoegB+XOWdia3OLtODujCVQt+yOII6GEYHgwBY9eAbsPh2NdHrCEiV18uBL-fm1AB2YkXxGQ4qXCbMIXpC4mRZM9OQwaIDSHJUsAAC2AhhSXgckU3lTojX-WEAA4AjQzVoMZZl3FTQt9R5IcgA)

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment!! I didn't know about contextual typing (explicitly know about it at least) and that was a good quick read!

Yeah, most of my use cases are when the `data` being operated isn't known by the transforming function, but in some cases it is and I was hoping I could figure out a way to have TS figure it out.

Yeah, the auto-currying approach is ideal, but usually too much to do with all functions I write. In the case of two args, it's not so bad, but gets worse. I've yet to find a `curry` function that works well (ramda or otherwise). Might you know of one?

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out write up.

Comment: @jcalz `<T>(x: { name: T })` is exactly the type for `x` of the function argument that TS should infer. You should only have to type `x` explicitly if you want to spezialize to a more specific type.

Comment: @bob Automatically inferring generic types for concrete functions would probably be very expensive for the compiler; every unannotated parameter would become generic, and carrying those generics around would almost certainly hinder performance. I'm also not sure that there'd be much support for making the compiler so permissive. The argument "`x => x.name` should not be an error and `x` should be inferred as something that makes it not an error" would also imply that `let x = "hello"; x = 3;` should give no errors and `x` should be inferred as `string | number`.

Comment: The latter point about permissiveness might be summed up best in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15114#issuecomment-293415353) of [microsoft/TypeScript#15114](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15114).

Comment: @jcalz This behavior was kind of a shock to me since I'm used to the ML family type systems. Thanks for the insight! It makes more sense now.