# what is the correct way to use keyof in a curried function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My biggest struggle with typescript is this simple usecase

```js
type Prop = <O, K extends keyof O>(key: K) => (obj: O) => O[K]
```

Is there a way to make TS give correct hints/autocomplete suggestions, when I write the following and place my cursor between the quotes?

```js
const user = { name: "Andreas", age: 30 }
const a = prop("")(user)
```

I have tried a bunch of different typings, including repeating generics in the returned function and whatelse not, but nothing seems to work.

So I wonder why cannot we define types in reverse like so

```js
type Prop = <K extends keyof O>(key: K) => <O>(obj: O) => O[K]
```

Couldn't the type parser read everything in and then resolve the type inference order in a more clever way?

Comment: No, the compiler can't push contextual typing backwards through function calls like that.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9JdJm) meet your needs instead?  If so I can write up an answer and explain what's going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68624500/2887218

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191355/typescript-generics-dont-apply-to-previous-function-when-curried-how-to

Comment: @jcalz unfortunately it doesn't, neither of the cases suggest property names. The constraint works but that wasn't the issue :(

Comment: Then TypeScript can't do what you want.  Even if it could, I don't quite see the appeal; could you spell it out for me?  The only way auto-suggesting names makes sense is when you immediately call the returned function like `prop("age")(user)` and not if you actually use currying for partial application like `const getAge = prop(age);` and later `getAge(user);`, right?  If you can only get suggestions when you immediately pass in both arguments, why use currying at all?  Would [this](//tsplay.dev/wRJYXw) not work better for you? If you need the compiler to know about both args, pass both args.

Comment: well the thing is that I love to use ramda, but their TS types are mediocre at best, not due to lack of skills but probably due to limitations of TS itself. However, the types are also very old, so I was trying to improve some of them, and ramda puts the data that is operated on always last. Hence the need to infer stuff backwards. Thank again for your time, though.